# SSL certificate on ec2 instance using load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am using 4200 port t run my application. I have issued one ssl certifficate from aws also.
Please let me know how can I transfer traffic to 4200 as by default its using https.

Answer (score 0):

To use HTTPS the resource the client connects to needs to have an SSL installed.

For your purpose you should create an [Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html) with a [listener](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html) for HTTPS running port 443. The default certificate would need to be the certificate you've added. If you added in [ACM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-overview.html) ensure that it is located in the same region as the load balancer.

The listener would connect to a [target group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html) containing your instance, this would be registered to use the 4200 port on your instance (with the HTTP protocol). Ensure that the security groups allow access from the load balancer to your EC2 instance.

If you've not ever created an ALB before these links may be useful:

- [Create an Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-application-load-balancer.html)
- [Create an HTTPS listener for your Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html)

Comment: Hi, ec2 instance port by default its taking http. How can I manage these 3 ports on load balancer?

Comment: So for the load balancer listener you would add the ports your clients want to access (80 for HTTP, 443 for HTTPS). Then for the target group you would add one target group per servers/ports combo.

Comment: No problem, glad this is now fixed for you :)